# How to create a custom JSON mapping for nested (data)classes with SQLAlchemy (2)

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I want to persist a python (data)class (i.e. `Person`) using imperative mapping in SQLAlchemy. One field of this class refers to another class (`City`). The second class is only a wrapper around two dicts and I want to store it in a denormalized way as a JSON column.

My example classes look like this:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
  name: str
  city: City


@dataclass
class City:
 property_a: dict
 property_b: dict
```

And in the database it should look like this:

```
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  name  |                              city                               |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| aaron  | {property_a: {some_value: 1}, property_b: {another_value: 2}}   |
| bob    | {property_a: {some_value: 10}, property_b: {another_value: 20}} |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My table definition looks like this:

```
person_table = Table(
  "persons",
   Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
   Column("name", String),
   Column("city", JSON)
)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
  Person,
  person_table
)
```

This fails (obviously) since "Object of type City is not JSON serializable". I need to provide custom (de)serialization methods to the `mapper_registry` which tell SqlAlchemy how to convert my `City` class into a nested dict and back. But I could not find out how to do this (and even if this is a good approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Whether this is an elegant way to solve this problem or not is for the reader to decide. My initial reasoning was not to pollute the models with I/O implementation details. Another approach would be to introduce a service layer and/or create additional dumb DTOs that can be translated to/from the model classes and contain the `city` fields as plain dicts/json.

Two additional functions are needed to introduce custom de-/serialization:

```
def serialize_json(o):
  match o:
    case City():
       return json.dumps({"property_a": o.property_a, "property_b": o.property_b})
    case _:
      return json.dumps(o)

def deserialize_json(s):
  s_dict = json.loads(s)
  match s_dict:
    case {"property_a": property_a, "property_b": property_b}:
      return City(property_a=property_a, property_b=propertyb)
    case _:
      return s_dict
```

The match operator is not strictly necessary for this toy example, but keeps everything a little bit cleaner if more of those cases are needed.

Now the functions can be passed to SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
  "sqlite:///:memory:", 
  json_serializer=orm.serialize_json, 
  json_deserializer=orm.deserialize_json
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `DeclarativeBase` and `Mapped` features of SQLAlchemy 2, you can make your own [`TypeDecorator`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/custom_types.html) to serialize your dataclasses to json.

To make it work, you will need to implement a custom `JSONEncoder`, and also add a `__post_init__` method to your dataclass so it can deserialize itself.

It will be much simpler if you use a library like pydantic or marshall. The following example uses no additional libraries.

```
import enum
import json
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass

from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped
from sqlalchemy.types import VARCHAR, TypeDecorator


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    city: City

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not isinstance(self.city, City):
            self.city = City(**self.city)


@dataclass
class City:
   property_a: dict
   property_b: dict


class DataclassEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """Simple JSON encoder that encodes dataclasses and enums."""

    def default(self, o):
        if is_dataclass(o):
            return asdict(o)
        if isinstance(o, enum.Enum):
            return o.value
        return super().default(o)


class DataclassType(TypeDecorator):
    """SQLA Type decorator to serialize dataclasses"""

    impl = VARCHAR
    cache_ok = True

    def __init__(self, base_cls):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_cls = base_cls

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return json.dumps(value, cls=DataclassEncoder)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        result = json.loads(value)
        return self.base_cls(**result)

# Using the DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    # register the type decorator with each type used.
    type_annotation_map = {
        Person: DataclassType(Person),
    }

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"

    person: Mapped[Person]
```